# My jquery and css sticky bar,doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the script i used to make the sticky bar adjust to the scroll

```js
<script language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).scroll(function () {

  console.log($(window).scrollTop())
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 59) {
  $('#bar).addClass('bar-fixed');
  }
  if ($(window).scrollTop() < 61) {
  $('#bar').removeClass('bar-fixed');
  }
  });
  });
  </script>
  <script language="javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).foundation();
  })
  </script>
```

```css
this is the css code made for the page and the sticky bar before being sticky and after becoming sticky(notice plz that the page is coded with flex so that the two side bars adjust to the center one


  @import "compass/css3";
  iframe.youtube-player {
  align: center;}
  .wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;  
  display: 

  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;

  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  }

  .wrapper > * {
  padding: 0px;
  flex: 1 100%;
  }
  .bar-fixed {
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;

  }

  #bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;  
  background-color: #595959;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
  }
  .topsec {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;  
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #88888;
  text-align:left;
  display:inline-block;
  }
  .footer {
  height: 150px;  
  background-color: #333333;

  box-shadow: inset 0 20px 20px -20px black;

  }

  .main {
  text-align: left;
  background-color:white;
  min-height:1024px;
  margin-top: 55px;

  }

  .LB {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;text-align: left;max-width:200px;min-width:200px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 20px 20px -20px #888888;
  }

  .RB {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;text-align: left;max-width:200px;min-width:200px;
  margin-top: 1px;box-shadow: inset 0 20px 20px -20px #888888;
  }

  @media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .aside { flex: 1 auto; }
  }

  @media all and (min-width: 800px) {
  .main    { flex: 10 0px; }
  .LB { order: 1; } 
  .main    { order: 2; }
  .RB { order: 3; }
  .footer  { order: 4; }
  }


  body {
  padding: 0px;margin:0px;
  }
```

```html
this is the html code where i put my script at the end 


  <div class="topsec">
  </div>

  <div id="bar">
  <nav ></nav>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <article class="main">
  </article>
  <aside class="aside LB"></aside>
  <aside class="aside RB"></aside>
  <footer class="footer"></footer>
  </div>
```

Comment: My console says you have a syntax error!

Comment: Check your console for errors and isolate that part of the problem.

Comment: I am writing an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 59) {
    $('#bar').addClass('bar-fixed');
}else{
    $('#bar').removeClass('bar-fixed');
}
```

the problem with your code that you checked if
`$(window).scrollTop() > 59`  and then check if `$(window).scrollTop() < 61` so your code will addClass and removeit directly when you reached between 59 and 61  and I think its not that possible to get scroll between those numbers

> Note: be sure you include jquery

to include jquery put this code before closing body tag and before run any script or call a external js file

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> Note: This is one of more ways to include jquery .. you can use this
>   code for sure but for more information you should searching for how to
>   install jquery

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/k54onvyy/1/)

Comment: Well,true,that is very logic thank you for that,but it still doesn't work,though

Comment: @MrRobot did you include jquery?? .. then rearrange your css code .. put .bar-fixed after #bar  in css file

Comment: including that script in the <head> section just gave me a blank page,including it in body,before the actual script,didnt make any difference,and putting the bar-fixed after #bar did also make pretty much everything disappear

Comment: @MrRobot and in $('#bar).addClass( you forget '  so use $('#bar').addClass(

Comment: @MrRobot you can check this too  its clear to your case http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/k54onvyy/1/

Comment: waw thanks dude,btw the ( ' ) is only wrong here in the website,but in my code its fine,i maybe messed it when i was copy/pasting...one last thing could u plz tell me what did u exactly do to make it work?

Comment: @MrRobot I rearrange classes like I said to you before .. and from last demo in my answer  I include jquery in the bottom of html code  then I run your script .. thats all  .. I add (') sign you forgot it and use if statement like I said in answer .. make scroll check if scrolltop > 59  addClass  and if its <59  remove this class .. that's it :)

Comment: i see,that was helpful !

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if this works. If not, please tell me what I can do to improve it.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var bar = document.getElementById('bar');
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    var scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
    if (scrollTop < 59) {
      bar.className = '';
    }
    if (scrollTop > 61) {
      bar.className = 'bar-fixed';
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@import "compass/css3";
 iframe.youtube-player {
  align: center;
}
.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
.wrapper > * {
  padding: 0px;
  flex: 1 100%;
}
.bar-fixed {
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
#bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #888888;
}
.topsec {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #88888;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
.footer {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #333333;
  box-shadow: inset 0 20px 20px -20px black;
}
.main {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: white;
  min-height: 1024px;
  margin-top: 55px;
}
.LB {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 20px 20px -20px #888888;
}
.RB {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 20px 20px -20px #888888;
}
@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .aside {
    flex: 1 auto;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
  .main {
    flex: 10 0px;
  }
  .LB {
    order: 1;
  }
  .main {
    order: 2;
  }
  .RB {
    order: 3;
  }
  .footer {
    order: 4;
  }
}
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.bar-fixed {
  position: fixed;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topsec">
</div>

<div id="bar">
  <nav></nav>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <article class="main">
  </article>
  <aside class="aside LB"></aside>
  <aside class="aside RB"></aside>
  <footer class="footer"></footer>
</div>
```

Comment: it works greatly yes,but whats the difference between my jquery,and yours?is it simply a different way of coding?or does it also affect performance?

Comment: My code is JavaScript. JQuery is actually just a mutation of JavaScript. In fact JQuery just includes a library of functions that are JavaScript. You might want to look up how jquery works or something like that.

Comment: I generally code in JavaScript. I think your code was riddled with syntax errors. There may have also been a logical error in the way you were thinking when you programmed it.